# Marklogic SVC-BAD Codepoint error when using Rest API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a custom rest end point (POST) and pass some key values pairs and in my endpoint I takes these key value pairs and create an xml document.. here is  the code

```
let $enevelope := <document-enevelope>
                     <metadata>
                     {
                       let $extraProperties := xdmp:get-request-field-names()
                       for $x at $i in $extraProperties
                           let  $val := xdmp:get-request-field($x)
                            return
                               if(repoLoad:isEmpty($val)) then ()
                                 else
                                    element {fn:normalize-space($x)} {$val}}
                       }
                        </metadata>
    </document-enevelope>
let $_ := xdmp:document-insert($docEnevelopeURI, $enevelope,(xdmp:default-permissions()), ())
```

All this works, but when I am sending to my POST request this key/value pair

```
"Experiment_name":"X13-284-285-A-1516147.0-V1ß iv.po.ip.b.CSF.rat."
```

I get the following error `Error: AppRequestTask::run: SVC-BAD: Bad CodepointIterator::_next`

The request I sent is not even coming to my custom rest endpoint.. I did encode the key/value in UTF-8.. I am confused as to what is wrong.. But in query console I do the same insert with the same key/value it works..

What am I doing wrong..  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by URLEncoding the parametes in UTF-8 and in my rest service in Marklogic I did the `xdmp:url-decode` that fixed my issue...

My Marklogic Rest service calling in java so before calling I do `URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8")` and in my Marklogic service endpoint I decode the params by calling `xdmp:url-decode`